# There is no word or excel or ppt document preview in alfresco

Tags: ms-office, alfresco, openoffice.org

I installed alfresco community edition 4.2e, I am able to preview the pdf and image files. But I am not able to preview the doc or xls or ppt file formats. I did a binary installation and I didnt modify anything.

Comment: did you include libre office installation?

Comment: You are asking from binary installation right? Yes I checked libre office while installing alfresco and it is there in my installation folder

Comment: When I click the documents it is getting downloaded

Comment: Okay the preview is there in alfresco share, but its not there in explorer. When I click the view in browser option in both share and explorer it is getting downloaded

Comment: That sounds about right. Only Share has a preview, and "View In Browser" requires your browser to be able to do a native preview

Comment: But I am able to preview the pdf files in explorer, is there any way to preview office files?

Comment: I'm guessing you have something like the Acrobat plugin or pdfjs installed in your browser, for in-browser renderings of PDF files? All you need to do is find the same thing for office.... Or get Alfresco to transform your office documents to PDF, and preview them

Comment: @Gagravarr if I transform them to pdf will it create pdf file for the same doc or ppt file? and how can I transform them

Comment: To transform from one format to another, eg DOC -> PDF, you want either [Content Transformers](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformations) or [Rendition Service](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Rendition_Service). You can setup a Rule in Share to trigger it for you - `Transform and Copy`

Comment: @Gagravarr i have already uploaded the files in the share. Will it transform those files to pdf and create another copy of it ? Because I have limited space.

Comment: Up to you - if you don't mind burning CPU cycles you can transform it on the fly, the more common option is to have one folder for PDFs which people view in, and other for the "raw" office documents (which then get transformed)

Comment: @Gagravarr I am afraid I cant do that with my limited storage, the preview of these files are taking long time to load. I even tried with media viewer add on. I guess I have to go with chrome office viewer extension then.

Comment: You'll just have to stick with the Alfresco Share previews then!

Comment: @Gagravarr is there any way to use content transformation without a rule?